# CSS - left border of button is rounded on the right side

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

In an Ionic mobile app, I want to add a thick left `border` to buttons. But as you can see in the screenshot the right side of this left `border` seems rounded.

I already tried to solve this by setting the `border-radius` to 0, but that has no effect.

```css
.button-viztype {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.button-distribution {
  border-left-color: #1B3D77;
}
.button-comparison {
  border-left-color: #397EF6;
}
.button-composition {
  border-left-color: #6181B8;
}
.button-relationship {
  border-left-color: #82ADF6;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-distribution button-full button-viztype">
      Distribution
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-comparison button-full button-viztype">
      Comparison
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-composition button-full button-viztype">
      Composition
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-relationship button-full button-viztype">
      Relationship
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Right side of left border is rounded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the button border:

https://jsfiddle.net/uwnyds3s/

```
.button-viztype {
    border: none;
    height:75px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #c3c3c3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to reset the `border` for `button`

```css
button {
  border: 0
}
.button-viztype {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.button-distribution {
  border-left-color: #1B3D77;
}
.button-comparison {
  border-left-color: #397EF6;
}
.button-composition {
  border-left-color: #6181B8;
}
.button-relationship {
  border-left-color: #82ADF6;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-distribution button-full button-viztype">
      Distribution
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-comparison button-full button-viztype">
      Comparison
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-composition button-full button-viztype">
      Composition
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-relationship button-full button-viztype">
      Relationship
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see what you are referring to but you have to reset all the border widths first

```css
.button-viztype {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.button-distribution {
  border-left-color: #1B3D77;
}
.button-comparison {
  border-left-color: #397EF6;
}
.button-composition {
  border-left-color: #6181B8;
}
.button-relationship {
  border-left-color: #82ADF6;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="button button-distribution button-full button-viztype">
      Distribution
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your other edges have a border. You can override defaults and set the borders like this:

```
.button-viztype {
    border: none;
    border-left: 7px solid #1B3D77;
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```html
**Reset your Border of button to none **

.button-viztype {  
    border: none;  
    border-left: 7px solid #1B3D77;  
}
```